# How can I correctly plot my qualitative variables in FAMD analysis using FactoMineR?

Tags: r, binary, pca, factominer

community!

I'm trying to run FAMD on a morphology-based dataset with 25 qualitative variables recording the presence and absence of fluorescence on a body part (binary) and six quantitative variables. Furthermore, I have a few supplementary variables such as sex, genus and depth.

First I ran the code for the FAMD on my data set after I had removed all missing values with na.omit():

```
res.famd1<-FAMD(fluo_famd1,sup.var=c(1,2,28,35),graph=FALSE, ncp=5)
```

and retrieved a bunch of results like eigenvalues, scree plot etc.
I then tried to plot my qualitative variables within the two dimensions like in this example:
[Example][1]

This is the code I used:

```
quali.var1 <- get_famd_var(res.famd1, "quali.var")

quali.var1

fviz_famd_var(res.famd1, "quali.var")
```

Instead of plotting the categories R is plotting decimal numbers I can't explain.
[Missing categories][2]

After this I tried running the FAMD on my data set with missing values using the code given in the package description:

```
require(missMDA)

res.impute <- imputeFAMD(fluo_famd2, ncp=3)

res.famd2 <- FAMD(fluo_famd2,tab.disj=res.impute$tab.disj,sup.var=c(1,2,28))
```

When trying to plot the categories now, they do appear in the plot but they are doubled and labelled with _0 and _1.
[doubled categories][3]

My questions are:
Can you identify an obvious mistake? Why would the categories be plotted twice in the graph? Does it have an impact on the overall analysis? Is FAMD suited for a data set like this?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UFlA.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qb3Cz.png
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Dff.png

Please find a subset of my data here:

```
structure(list(genus = structure(c(5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 
9L, 9L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 7L, 6L, 7L), .Label = c("Cryptochirus", 
"Dacryomaia", 
"Fizesereneia", "Fungicola", "Hapalocarcinus", "Hiroia", 
"Lithoscaptus", 
"Neotroglocarcinus", "Opecarcinus", "Pseudohapalocarcinus", 
"Xynomaia"
), class = "factor"), sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("f", "m"), class 
= 
"factor"), 
frontal_dorsal = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = 
"factor"), 
frontal_ventral = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = 
"factor"), 
mesogastric = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = 
"factor"), 
cardial = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
branchial = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
ps1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
ps2 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
ps3 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
ps4 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
ps6 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
telson = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
eyes = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
eyestalk = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), 
antennules = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = 
"factor"), 
anntenullar_peduncle = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class 
= 
"factor"), 
depth = c(NA, 10.3, 16, 16.1, 14.3, 12.8, 10.8, 12.6, 10.2, 
11, 11.9, 13.1, 10.7, 10.1, 12.3), carapace_fluo = c(NA, 
NA, 0.0999104660846311, 0.459446596994549, 0.639459602769835, 
0.0157309627508303, NA, 0.792912115871697, 0.385646421420439, 
0.0934932558564838, 0.118926192063408, 0.334765757290687, 
NA, 0.712954991372207, 0.816431146170724), ap_fluo = c(NA, 
0, 0.153709650160554, NA, 0.526410945516736, 0, 
0.0572985597508758, 
NA, 0.0105633802816901, 0.284174213022855, 0.305258467023173, 
0.402286503491138, NA, 0, 0.0679211592610398), prod_fluo = c(NA, 
0, 0, NA, 0.528576376861794, 0, 0, 0.15260360009031, 0, 
0.0252962625341841, 
0.241194486983155, 0.0717077570655442, NA, 0.479219143576826, 
0), pol_fluo = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.118164567879938, 
0, 0, 1, 0, NA, 0.299160251924423, 0), dac_fluo = c(NA, 0, 
0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0.102848534648042, 0, 0, 0.309536216779573, 
0, NA, 0.0654761904761905, 0), sum_chel = c(NA, 0, 0, NA, 
0.345118733509235, 0, 0, 0.14349725008088, 0, 0.0155266470835082, 
0.347599820547331, 0.0451661774453177, NA, 0.32612422524067, 
0)), row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Comment: Greetings! It would be helpful to provide a minimal reproducible dataset for us to work with. One way is by using `dput`. You can see how to use this command in the following video: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Please find the code in the question. Thanks!